How to make Traefik in container and gitlab in native host working together
I'm running the Traefik in docker container, and it has two entrypoints 80/443. I have another gitlab services running in native host which is listening 9043.

mydomain.com -- traefik
mydomain.com:9043 -- gitlab
How can I hide the 9043 from gitlab url by using traefik forward? The final URL I want to get is "https://gitlab.example.com" or "https://example.com/gitlab"
Here is my current configure, but it seems the configuration is not working.

external_url = "https://example.com:9043

http:
  routers:
    gitlab:
      entrypoints: http
      rule: Host(`gitlab.example.com`)
      middlewares: gitlab-https-redirect
      service: gitlab

    gitlab-secure:
      entrypoints: https
      rule: Host(`gitlab.example.com`)
      tls: true
      service: gitlab
  
  middlewares:
    gitlab-https-redirect:
      redirectscheme:
        scheme: https

  services:
    gitlab:
      loadBalancer:
        servers:
          - url: https://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:9043

